# Difference between Semaphore, mutual exclusion, monitor with respect to achieve the synchronization

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, synchronization, multiprocessing

I'm studying Operating System with myself and I'm getting very confused that what is the difference in Semaphore, Monitor and mutual exclusion, all this terms are sound very similar to achieve synchronization ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the old days we just talked about LOCKS. There are generally two types of locks that can be put on a resource

- Exclusive access to a resource
- Multiple Read Only access to a resource.

MUTEX/MUTUAL EXCLUSION/LOCK are all the same thing.

There are many ways to implement locks. Semaphores and monitors are methods of implementing locks.

Comment: can you brief me about semaphore and monitors  ?

Comment: For a start, you could go to the WIKIPEDIA articles. They describe them fully.